# Filter search 2 models with out any relationship between these models

Tags: javascript, laravel

this is controller code

```
  public function alluser(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $query = $data['query'];
        $data2 = User::where('id', $query)
    ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
    ->with('Department:id,name,email')
    ->orWhereHas('Department', function ($q) use ($query) {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%");
    })->get();
                return response()->json($data2);
      
    }
```

this is the javascript code

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var route = "{{ url('autocomplete1') }}";
        $('#frst_name22').typeahead({
         source: function(query, process) {
            return $.get(route,{query:query},function(data){
               return process(data);
            });
         }
        });
   });
</script>
```

i am trying to build a search like https://oladoc.com/ which we filter doctor hospital. my code is not working.[image]

Comment: First you should return 2 values one for doctor list and other for hospital list then limit to 3 or 4 for both and then get display data i am just gessing as i dont know the full structure